# Open PDF with specified page (example: direction to page 3)

Tags: xcode, ipad, pdf

At the moment I show my PDFs in a webview. Now my user always wants the third page of the pdf to be shown directly. Can you give me some hints how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe (semi-officially) defined this method for accessing a PDF page directly via an URI:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/file.pdf#page=3
```

You can read more about these recommendations in [**PDF Open Parameters (PDF, page 7)**](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=7).

Whether your iPad PDF viewer will act according to this guideline is a completely different kettle of fish though...

Comment: But how can I integrate this into my existing app? Like I mentioned, normally the user just switched in my app to the pdf-view which is simply a uiwebview...

Comment: @user1066006: but how does your uiwebview now which file to display?? You may be able to use `file:///path/to/file.pdf#page=3`...

Comment: Right now I use: "[self.pdfview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];" So adding "#page=3" just leads to showing a simply white pdf without the content...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "go-to" PDF action for the "document-open" event. A compliant PDF viewer component or application will automatically navigate to the specified page when the document is opened in it.

Here is an example of such a PDF: http://www.gnostice.com/newsletters/downloads/2011_03/PDF_that_skips_to_page_3_by_default.pdf

Adobe Reader will correctly open page 3 of this document when it is opened. You need to check if the PDF viewer in your application supports this feature of PDF.